# How to obtain Detele

Tags: list-manipulation, charts

From

```
a={{6, 4}, {8, 1}, {11, 3}}
```

How to obtain

```
{{6, 8, 11}, {6, 11}, {6,11}, {6}}
```

or

```
{{6}, {6, 11}, {6, 11}, {6, 8, 11},}
```

with `DeleteCases` or in a similar way?

The target is to generate a bar chart similar to this one with large numbers.
[image]

With this code

```
NumberLinePlot[{{6, 8, 11}, {6, 11}, {6, 11}, {6}}, Spacings -> {0.1}, PlotStyle ->     Directive[PointSize[0.016]], LabelStyle -> {16, Bold}, ImageSize -> Full, PlotTheme -> {{}}]
```

[image]

Because this other code seems to be not suitable to large numbers (when `iMax` is greater than 13, the balls are not round and the x legend is not readable).

```
frecabs = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 1, 0, 0, 3};
iMax = 11;
(*frecabs=Table[RandomInteger[10],{i,1,iMax}];*)
vals = Table[i, {i, 1, iMax}];
BarChart[frecabs, ChartStyle -> "DarkRainbow", ChartLabels -> vals , 
 LabelStyle -> {25}
 , Ticks -> {Automatic, Range[8]}, GridLines -> {None, Range[8]}
 , ChartElements -> {Graphics[Disk[]], {1, 1}}, BarSpacing -> Medium, 
 PlotLabel -> "Clase C"
 , PlotRange -> 9]
```

Comment: Try `Flatten[ConstantArray @@@ {{6, 4}, {8, 1}, {11, 3}}, {{2}, {1}}]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Flatten[ConstantArray @@@ a, {{2}, {1}}]
```

> ```
> {{6, 8, 11}, {6, 11}, {6, 11}, {6}}
> ```

(as suggested by J.M. in comments).

Alternatively, a composition of `PadRight` and `Transpose`:

```
Transpose @ PadRight[ConstantArray @@@ a, Automatic, "deleteme"] /. 
 "deleteme" -> Nothing
```

> ```
>  {{6, 8, 11}, {6, 11}, {6, 11}, {6}}
> ```

Comment: Shorter form: `Flatten[ConstantArray @@@ a, {2}]`